# Populate ListBox with filtered data from Advanced Filter

Tags: excel, vba

How do I populate my ListBox by the filtered data using VBA on Excel?

I placed a table form at `A5:D5`
I just want to make it appear on the ListBox. only the visible filtered data only in the column `A` and column `D`

Here's the Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("D13").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A35440:D35440").Select
    Range("D35440").Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A5:D35440").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("Sheet3!Criteria"), Unique:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). • Your question was already asked, see link above your question.